# How to Creat Multi-level numbering in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

How do I Create Multi-level numbering in PowerPoint 2007 (1.0 >> 1.1 >> 1.1.1 >> Etc.)

Answer (score 4):

The possibilities in Powerpoint are really limited and I have not found a way to directly do it on the slides.

But here's a workaround using MS Word:

1. Type in your outline in Microsoft Word 2007
2. Give it the formatting you need.
3. Select and copy the outline.
4. In PowerPoint - Home tab - Clipboard group - down arrow on the Paste button - Paste special
5. Choose paste as a Word object.

Comment: This works, but you can't easily animate the bullet items.  I personally don't find that to be a problem, but it's worth mentioning.